# Ubuntu 16.04 a lot of kworker processes

Tags: 16.04, kernel, cpu, optimization, interrupts

I have an ubuntu 16.04 server with kernel 4.10.0-37-generic. It's metal server, not virtual. There are a number of kworker processes (about 109-115), every kworker consumes CPU (up to 4%). Also I guess that they impact on load average.

I have also a VPS with same ubuntu version and same kernel. There are kworkers and they don't consu,e anything at all. And load average is very low. Both servers do the same things.

And my question is, what can I do to fix it at my metal server?

I looked throug a number of articles with solutions, where authors analyzed /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/, disabled something and got problem fixed. But at my server I have a very strange output for "grep . -r /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/":

```
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_gbl_lock:       0  EN     enabled      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe15:       0     STS invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe05:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe3F:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe33:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe2F:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe23:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1F:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe13:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0F:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe03:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe3D:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe31:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe2D:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe21:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1D:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe11:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_pwr_btn:       0  EN     enabled      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_slp_btn:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0D:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe01:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_pmtimer:       0     STS invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe3B:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe2B:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1B:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe38:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0B:       0         disabled     unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe28:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe18:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe08:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/sci:       0
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe36:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe26:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/error:       0
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe16:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe06:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_rt_clk:       0         disabled     unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe34:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe24:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe14:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe04:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe3E:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe32:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe2E:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe22:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1E:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe12:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0E:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe02:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe3C:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe30:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe2C:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe20:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1C:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe10:       0     STS invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe39:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0C:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe00:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe3A:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe29:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe2A:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe19:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1A:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe09:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe37:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0A:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe27:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe17:       0     STS invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/sci_not:       0
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe07:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe35:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe25:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe_all:       0
```

Zeroes are everywhere, a lot of invalids.. I have no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: do you have any update on this?